# How can i call a different functions seperately using a single button

Tags: javascript, html

I have to create a calculator but i have to use separate functions for add , subtract , division and multiply

there should be an equal to (=) button which upon clicking should display the result

operators should be selected using the dropdown box

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>calculator</title>

</head>
<body>
<h1 align="center">calculator</h1>
<script type="text/javascript">

function add()
{
var a=parseInt(document.getElementById("firstnumber").value);
var b=parseInt(document.getElementById("secondnumber").value);
var c=a+b
document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML=c;
}

function sub()
 { 
      var a=parseInt(document.getElementById("firstnumber").value);
      var b=parseInt(document.getElementById("secondnumber").value);
      var c=a-b;
      document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML=c;
 }

 function mul()
 { 
  var a=parseInt(document.getElementById("firstnumber").value);
      var b=parseInt(document.getElementById("secondnumber").value);
      var c=a*b;
      document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML=c;
 }

 function div()
 { 
  var a=parseInt(document.getElementById("firstnumber").value);
      var b=parseInt(document.getElementById("secondnumber").value);
      var c=a/b;
      document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML=c;
 }

</script>
<p>First Number: <input id="firstnumber"></p>
<p>Second Number: <input id="secondnumber"></p>
<select id="operators">
  <option value="add" onclick="add()">+</option>
  <option value="sub" onclick="sub()">-</option>
  <option value="mul" onclick="mul()">*</option>
  <option value="div" onclick="div()">/</option>
</select>

<button onclick="add.call(this);sub.call(this);mul.call(this);div.call(this);">=</button>
<p id="answer"></p>

</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think thats what you were looking for.
make sure to read what i wrote under the code

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>calculator</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 align="center">calculator</h1>
    <p>First Number: <input id="firstnumber" /></p>
    <p>Second Number: <input id="secondnumber" /></p>
    <select id="operators">
      <option value="add">+</option>
      <option value="sub">-</option>
      <option value="mul">*</option>
      <option value="div">/</option>
    </select>

    <button id="calcBtn">=</button>
    <p id="answer"></p>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

script.js:

```
document.getElementById("calcBtn").addEventListener("click", () => {
  let operator = document.getElementById("operators").value;
  let a = parseInt(document.getElementById("firstnumber").value);
  let b = parseInt(document.getElementById("secondnumber").value);
  switch (operator) {
    case "add":
      add();
      break;
    case "sub":
      sub();
      break;
    case "mul":
      mul();
      break;
    case "div":
      div();
      break;

    default:
      break;
  }
  function add() {
    let c = a + b;
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = c;
  }

  function sub() {
    let c = a - b;
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = c;
  }

  function mul() {
    let c = a * b;
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = c;
  }

  function div() {
    let c = a / b;
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = c;
  }
});
```

- dont use onclick, give element an id and then add event listenner to it works the same but addeventlistenner is better you can replace `.addEventListener("click", () => {` with `.addEventListener("click", function() {`
  its up to you
- always place your script tag directly above the body tag
- use script src instead of script > code, it makes the html more clean
- use let instead of var
- switch case its like if, but in situations like that better, because its easier to write what to do depending on the value
  usage:

```
switch(variable){
    case "variable value":
        code
        break;
}
```

i think thats all